# Quorum Disk size for Windows 2008R2 failover

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I am setting up a two node failover cluster for SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Microsoft recommends minimum 512MB size LUN for the quorum disk and don't have a recommendation for the witness LUN. What do people typically run with for this type of set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space actually used by a quorum disk amounts at most to a few kilobytes, not even megabytes.   There is really no reason at all to go above the suggested size.

That said, creating a LUN and a NTFS volume of a few megabytes in size would be impractical for several reasons; the most common size for quorum disks in my experience is 1 GB, and even that is 99% wasted space.