# Quorum disk size for Windows Server 2019 failover cluster

Tags: failovercluster, windows-server-2019

I'm setting up a Windows Server 2019 failover cluster, and I've seen advice to put the cluster quorum on its own LUN.  How much disk space should I dedicate to it?  It does not appear to take much space on my test cluster.  This cluster will be used for MS SQL, if it makes a difference.

Similar question for Server 2008 : [Quorum Disk size for Windows 2008R2 failover](https://serverfault.com/questions/397674/quorum-disk-size-for-windows-2008r2-failover)

Comment: Most of the clusters I've seen used a quorum disk of 5 to 20 GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1GB wil be more than enough. Quorum disk stores only cluster configuration

Comment: I've gone the route of assigning a larger but thin-provisioned disk, and indeed, it hasn't grown from day 1.